# How do i store a binary number in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, random, binary, decimal

Ok, so i been working on this right here that is intended to be part of a encryption software that works synonymously like 2fa

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdio>     
 #include <cstdlib>   
 #include <ctime>    
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {


int RGX;
int box[32];

srand (time(NULL));


RGX = rand() % 100000000 + 9999999;

cout << "Random Generated One Time HEX #:" << endl;

cout << std::hex << RGX << endl;


while(RGX!=1 || 0)
{

int m = RGX % 2;
cout << " " << m << " ";


RGX = RGX / 2;


cout << RGX << endl;



} 

return 0;
}
```

Here is a sample of what it outputs:

```
Random Generated One Time HEX #:
3ff3c70
0 1ff9e38
0 ffcf1c
0 7fe78e
0 3ff3c7
1 1ff9e3
1 ffcf1
1 7fe78
0 3ff3c
0 1ff9e
0 ffcf
1 7fe7
1 3ff3
1 1ff9
1 ffc
0 7fe
0 3ff
1 1ff
1 ff
1 7f
1 3f
1 1f
1 f
1 7
1 3
1 1


** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **
```

The result is different each time since it's randomized, i'm still not finished. But what i need to know is how do i store the binary value in an array, the binary value are the numbers on the left.

Comment: `while(RGX!=1 || 0)` - what the....?

Comment: That's just to convert the random hex to binary

Comment: @LisandroGarciaMartinez What WhozCraig is getting at is that `a != b || 0` is exactly the same as `a != b` since `0` is just false. Also, can you comment on why you want to convert an integer to an array of integers representing its bits? Why is that more useful that just working with the integer itself?

Comment: That doesn't "convert" anything. It tests whether one of two conditions is true: (a) RGX != 1, and if that's false, (b) 0, which is *never* true. Regardless, how to store in an array with this code, how would you store into an array when prompting the user for input repetitively in a loop? Do that, but instead of prompting for input store the value of `m` on each iteration.

Comment: `unsigned m = RGX & 0x1;` much faster than `int m = RGX % 2;` (although some compilers would do that as optimization). ALso any bit operations with signed ints may give you unexpected results. Then `RGX>>=1;`  if RGX is signed may produce non-zero bit with most significant digit for some compilers (certainly did with minGW). But you don't need to do those things manually even. All you need is `std::bitset`

Comment: you already have an array in the code. What prevents you from storing the numbers in the array? `box[i] = m`

Comment: No inside the brackets after " while(RGX!=1 || 0) " it uses % and divides by 2 up until it gets to 1 or 0. the 0s and 1s are what i'm trying to store. why am i using 1s and 0s has to do with an algorithm i plan to implement later on.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number hmm i'll look into that

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `RGX & 0x1` is not functionally the same as `RGX % 2`, thus a compare does not substitute them for each other. Example when `RGX == -1`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica naturally, it isn't if RGX is signed, it's not equal. but OP wanted it exactly as a bit detector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) instead of manually extracting bits and the array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> 
#include <cstdlib>   
#include <bitset>

int main() {
    srand (time(NULL));
    int RGX = rand() % 100000000 + 9999999;

    std::cout << "Random Generated One Time HEX #: \n";
    std::cout << std::hex << RGX << "\n";
    std::bitset<32> box(RGX);
    for (int i=0;i<32;++i){
        std::cout << box[i];
    }
 
}
```

[Possible output](https://godbolt.org/z/rfsKa8f5W):

```
Random Generated One Time HEX #: 
478ada7
11100101101101010001111000100000
```

---

> No inside the brackets after " while(RGX!=1 || 0) " it uses % and divides by 2 up until it gets to 1 or 0.

No. Thats not what that condition says. The condition says "loop while (`RGX` is not equal to `1`) or 0". As `0` is always `false` when converted to `bool`, your condition is equivalent to `while(RGX != 1)`.

Comment: bitset supports `operator<<`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie or `to_string`, the loop was just to demonstrate how to get individual bits, as I suppose thats what OP wants and because it is closest to using an array (what OP was actually asking for)

Answer (score 0):

You may use (no idea why you would) [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) to store unpacked collection of bits. And better use [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) for RNG facilities.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <bitset>
#include <random>
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 9999999);

    unsigned RGX = dist(rd);

    cout << "Random Generated One Time HEX #:" << std::endl;

    std::bitset<32> bits {RGX}; // E.g. bits[5] would give you 5th bit
   
    cout << std::hex << RGX << " contains "<< bits << std::endl;  

    return 0;
}
```